# Best way to make a 2 column layout that works with multiple resolutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've asked this a couple times but seems like I didn't word it quite right so will try do better here,

I'm trying to make a 2 column layout in HTML, CSS, & Java, what I want is the text on the left to center in the middle of both columns once the resolution is too low (by this I mean the columns look great in 1920x width and 1600x width, but when it gets down to 1200x800 the text breaks past the height of the right image).

I've seen a website that once the page width hits a certain point (around 1200x width) the text in the left column snaps to center in the middle of both, which results in the page looking good at all res. I have a feeling the text is overlayed on top of both columns with a java snippet that tells the text to move into the center at a certain width, only problem is I don't know how to achieve that,

I've attached my code at the bottom but in my version the text is inside the left column, am I right thinking that the text is probably on-top of both columns? and is there a javascript to tell the text to move center at a certain width? would really appreciate any help!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content1">
<div class="column1 animation fadeInUp">
<div class="title1">
<h3>STATEMENT</h3> . 
<h2>Title of Some Sort.</h2>
<div class="blue-line"></div>
</div>
<p1>Paragraph text.<br></p1>
<button class="svg1">FORUM</button>
<button class="svg2">SIGN UP</button>
</div>
<div class="column2">
<div class="column2pic"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content1 {
display: flex;
margin-left:100px;
margin-right:0px;
}

.column1 {
display:inline-block;
flex: 31%;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-right:50px;
opacity: 0; animation-play-state: paused;
}

.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-play-state: running;
}

.fadeInUp {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
animation-name: fadeInUp;
}


@keyframes fadeInUp {
from {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 2.5rem, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 2.5rem, 0);
}

to {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: none;
transform: none;
}

.column2 {
flex: 50%;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left:100px;
padding-top:0px;
width:50vw;
}

.column2pic {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0.0)), url(../Assets/Images/Content1pic);
background-size:cover;
z-index: 100;
width:50vw;
height:600px;
}
```

NOTE: the animation is just a simple effect for the left text to fade up, but don't mind if anyone excludes that part to keep it simple.

Let me know if you have any ideas! Thanks!

Comment: One thing that would make things easy in terms of responsiveness would be using flexbox, or existing CSS frameworks, such as Bootstrap. Both are responsive in design. I would suggest having a look at either of those. Alternatively, you could use media queries, if you prefer to build it yourself entirely. But then again, why reinvent the wheel? ;)

Comment: Here's a wordpress template that's doing exactly what I'd like my 2 column layout to do, from looking at this and pulling in the right side of the browser window you can see it snaps the text to center, is one of those frameworks how you think they are achieving it? https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53878.html (they've given it a class "elementor")

Comment: Bootstrap has the exact same functionality within its framework. All you need to do is look up the classes for it, e.g. `row`, `col`, `col-sm-`, `col-md-`, `col-lg-` etc. More here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use css `@media`. In your case, you will have to create `@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px)` with the style that you would like at this size. See below an example of it. I put the width to 400px to fit with this snippet. When you resize the browser window under 400px `@media only screen and (max-width: 400px)`, it lowers the text size `font-size: 20px;` and align it in the center `text-align: center;`.

```css
#mypic {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 560px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350");
  font-size: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #mypic {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="mypic">My Title In Picture!</div>
```

Comment: So for this website, https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53878.html is that what they are doing? its the "elementor" div in their site code. I'm not wanting to stop the screen getting smaller I'm wanting the 2 column layout to look good at separate resolutions, achieving it by moving the text from the left column to the middle of both columns once the resolution gets so low that the text tries to break out of its left container, resulting in way more space for the text at low resolution, like they do on the site like I've attached.

Comment: Yes this is it. You will need to use `@media`. If you run the snippet, you will see the text get align in the middle as soon it is getting smaller than 400px;

Comment: I made another example with the same text that you were talking about on the other website.

Comment: Just to check, I should remove the text from column 1 and place it inside the container instead with the @media affecting the container and not the columns?

Comment: You are totally right, and if you would like to have your both column containers acting the same way, give them the same class name.

Comment: Ok so I've removed the text elements from the left column and placed them in Content1 which wraps both columns, I then fixed all the text and stuff so that it's working, I used @media on the paragraph to keep it 37% to the left until the page hits 1200 also and it works, all the text snaps to the centre of content1, I then deleted column 1 because I thought it was kinda pointless, and used "float right" on the right column and placed its z-index behind the text. Only problem is the image is sitting below all the text and I can't seem to get it to the top of the container?

Comment: its almost as if the column2 div is acting like its outside content1 container but it is inside it?

Comment: Ok I fixed that, so now the image is floating top right of the container, and text on the left, but when I shrink the screen to the snap point, the text snaps to centre but wont cover the image, the text is wrapped with a zindex thats higher than the image of -1, shouldn't the text cover the image?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it by making the position:relative for everything except the image.